# search in sublists and match common elements with other sublist

Tags: python-3.x

i am searching for an answer but i didn't find anything about my problem.

```
x=[['100',220, 0.5, 0.25, 0.1],['105',400, 0.12, 0.56, 0.9],['600',340, 0.4, 0.7, 0.45]]

y=[['1','100','105','601'],['2','104','105','600'],['3','100','105','604']]
```

i want as result:

```
z=[['1','100',0.5,0.25,0.1,'105',0.12,0.56,0.9],['2','105',0.12,0.56,0.9,'600',0.4,0.7,0.45],['3','100',0.5, 0.25, 0.1,'105', 0.12, 0.56, 0.9]]
```

i want to search in list y and match list x with list y where i get a new list z that containts the common sublists.
this is just an example, normally contains list x and y 10000 sublists.

i compare out of y ['1','100','105','601'] and search the '100','105','601' in list x (example ['100',220, 0.5, 0.25, 0.1]). if i find a match i make a new list z.

Can someone help me?

Comment: matching happens on which numbers? .. please specify the logic for combining the lists

Comment: Are you just trying to compute the elements common to the flattened versions of the two lists?

Comment: i would like to make again a nested list.

Answer (score 0):

*Answer edited because comments*

You said in the comments:

> search the second, third and fourth number in each y. and compare that with the number on place one in list x

and

> then i would like to add (from list x) the numbers on place 1,3,4,5

Then try something like this:

```
x = [
    ['100', 220, 0.5, 0.25, 0.1],
    ['105', 400, 0.12, 0.56, 0.9],
    ['600', 340, 0.4, 0.7, 0.45]
]

y = [
    ['1', '100', '105', '601'],
    ['2', '104', '105', '600'],
    ['3', '100', '105', '604']
]

z = []

xx = dict((k, v) for k, _, *v in x)

for first, *yy in y:
    zz = [first]
    for n in yy:
        numbers = xx.get(n)
        if numbers:
            zz.append(n)
            zz.extend(numbers)
    z.append(zz)

print(z)
```

`z` should now be:

```
[['1', '100', 0.5, 0.25, 0.1, '105', 0.12, 0.56, 0.9],
 ['2', '105', 0.12, 0.56, 0.9, '600', 0.4, 0.7, 0.45],
 ['3', '100', 0.5, 0.25, 0.1, '105', 0.12, 0.56, 0.9]]
```

---

First, I convert `x` into a dictionary, for easy lookup.
The iteration pattern used here was introduced with [pep-3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) and works like this:

```
>>> head, *tail = range(5)
>>> head
0
>>> tail
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: But if I got you right: you are looking for the second numbers in the sublists of each y, and add only the smaller ones from x there?  No, i am search the second, third and fourth number in each y. and compare that with the number on place one in list x.

Comment: Sorry, I am no native speaker.. And I think I made some mistake in the text (you quoted).  ``yy`` in the code contains the second, third and fourth number in each ``y``. if one of those (``n``) is on place one of ``x`` (``numbers=xx.get(n)``) what do you do with them now? add only the smaller numbers <= ``n`` ?

Comment: than i would like to add (from list x) the numbers on place 1,3,4,5

Comment: This is what the modified part in the lower part does. I'll edit the answer for  the correct verision

Comment: it works with this solution. thanks everybody for answering my question